# Table is not showing data accordingly in Reactjs

Tags: html, css, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to show the response from API into the react-semantic-ui table. After setting the state with fetch data, I need to place the first-order keys as the column name and then the second-order keys as the row name and the values of the second-order keys will be shown in the table-body. I have done this far which results in doubling the number of cells in each row while setting all cell values with the same data.

```
class NonProtectedFeatureBias extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {       
            staticPostData:{
                dataset_id: 1
            },
            tableData:{},
            tableColumnNames:[],
        };
    }
    renderKeys (data) {
        let tcolumn = [];
        for(let i=0; i<Object.keys(data).length;i++){
            const Obj1 = Object.keys(data)[i];
            //console.log(Obj1)
            tcolumn.push(Obj1);

        }
        let col = tcolumn.map(item=>{
            return <Table.HeaderCell>{item}</Table.HeaderCell>
        })
        return col
    }
    renderValues (data) {
        let row=null;
        for(let i=0; i<Object.keys(data).length;i++){
            const Obj1 = Object.values(data)[i];

            let trows = [];
            const Obj2 = Object.keys(Obj1).map(item =>{
                trows.push(item);
            });

            let tvalues =[];
            const Obj3 = Object.values(Obj1).map(item =>{
                tvalues.push(item);
                console.log(item)
            });
            row = trows.map(item=>{
                return(
                    <Table.Row  className="cell-current">
                        <Table.Cell className="cell-width-single">{item}</Table.Cell>
                        {tvalues.map(val =>{
                            return <Table.Cell selectable>{val}</Table.Cell>
                            //console.log(val)
                        })}
                    </Table.Row>
                )
            })
        }

        return row
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData();
    }
    fetchData(){
        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/GetProxyTable', this.state.staticPostData)
         .then((response) =>{

            var count = Object.keys(response.data).length;
            this.setState({tableData:response.data})
            console.log(response.data)
        });
    }
    render(){
        return ( 
            <Container style={{height:"250px", backgroundColor:""}}>
                <Table definition >
                    <Table.Header>
                    <Table.Row className="cell-with-no-padding">
                        <Table.HeaderCell />
                        {this.renderKeys(this.state.tableData)}
                    </Table.Row>
                    </Table.Header>

                    <Table.Body>
                        {this.renderValues(this.state.tableData)}
                    </Table.Body>
                </Table>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
export default NonProtectedFeatureBias;
```

This is the response I get from the API

[image]

And this is what I want to achieve,
[image]

This is what I am getting now,
[image]

Is this the right approach to achieve my goal?! I hope there is a much-optimized way to do this. And I am also needed to be able to click on a cell and get the regarding row and column name. Any suggestions or advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: `renderKeys` can be simplified to `Object.keys(data).map(item=>(<Table.HeaderCell>{item}</Table.HeaderCell>))`, for one. `map` pushes the results onto an array, so you can drop the boilerplate.

Comment: thank you! this really simplifies the renderKeys method. will you please take a look into the other one, renderValues?

Comment: Give it shot yourself first, to make sure you understand what I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `renderValues` are mapping through columns and not rows. Plus, you are setting each fake row to the same values, so all 'rows' are equal. lastly, returns the last one, which means last column values.

you can try code below which maps the columns to a rows object first before rendering the rows:

```
renderValues (data) {
  const rows = {}
  Object.values(data).forEach(col => {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(col)) {
      rows[key] = rows[key] ? [...rows[key], value] : [value]
    }
  })

  return Object.entries(rows).map(([item, values]) => (
    <Table.Row className="cell-current">
      <Table.Cell className="cell-width-single">{item}</Table.Cell>
        { values.map(val => <Table.Cell selectable>{val}</Table.Cell> ) }
    </Table.Row>
  ))
}
```

Comment: works like a charm! now I get it where the issue of my code was. :D  thank you so much (peace)

Comment: as for now I can easily get the row name of a cell using onClick={()=>alert(item)}}. it is obvious that if I use only the parameter "data" inside this alert(), this will get all the of the column names. now, please at least suggest to me how to get the column name from the current code along with your code.

Comment: try to add array to rows instead like: `rows[key] = rows[key] ? [...rows[key], [col, value] ] : [ [col, value] ]`. now once you iteract over values to create `Table.Cell`, `val` will be an array and you can do `values.map(([col, value]) => ...`. You could also store as an object instead of an array like `{ [col]: value }`, but then at map `val` would be an object and you yould have to do `Object.values(val)` to extract its content.

Comment: The table rows and table cells should probably have `key` props, right?